# create a GATE document from a CSV file

Tags: perl, csv, gate

I need to transform a csv document structured like that:

```
i love iphone \t positive
i hate iphone \t negative
```

to a gate document which include the related class:

[image]

what is the best way to do that ? jape, groovy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have to deal with CSV and GATE document. If you search on CPAN you'll find modules which can handle these type of documents easily.

- [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV)
- [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS)
- [NLP::GATE::Document](https://metacpan.org/pod/NLP::GATE::Document)

So you may use Text::CSV to get the text out of CSV file and use `setText`, `setAnnotationSet` methods of NLP::GATE::Document module to creat, set text and annotate a GATE document.

Try it out and if you face any problem then ask again with the code you've tried so far to achieve your goal.

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the easier answer but it works with this perl script:

```
use strict;
use locale;
use HTML::Entities;

open (IN,$ARGV[0])
    or die "file doesn't exist ! : $!\n";

my $i = 0;

while (my $form = <FICHIER>) {

    if ($form =~ /^((.+)\t(.+))$/)

    {   
        my $file = "tweet_".$i.".xml";
        # Use the open() function to create the file.
        unless(open FILE, '>'.$file) {
        # Die with error message 
        # if we can't open it.
        die "nUnable to create $file";
        }           

        my $sentence =$2;
        my $encoded_sent = encode_entities($sentence);

        my $class = $3;
        my $length_sent = length($sentence);

        ##head xml
        print FILE "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"."\n";
        print FILE '<GateDocument version="3">'."\n";
        print FILE '<GateDocumentFeatures>'."\n";
        print FILE '<Feature>'."\n";
        print FILE '<Name className="java.lang.String">gate.SourceURL</Name>'."\n";
        print FILE '<Value className="java.lang.String">created from String</Value>'."\n";
        print FILE '</Feature>'."\n";
        print FILE '</GateDocumentFeatures>'."\n";

        ##create xml for each line  -- here is the content
        print FILE '<TextWithNodes><Node id="0"/>'.$encoded_sent.'<Node id="'.$length_sent.'"/></TextWithNodes>'."\n";

        print FILE '<AnnotationSet Name="Key">'."\n";
        print FILE '<Annotation Id="1" Type="Tweet" StartNode="0" EndNode="'.$length_sent.'">'."\n";

        print FILE '<Feature>'."\n";
        print FILE '<Name className="java.lang.String">class</Name>'."\n";
        print FILE '<Value className="java.lang.String">'.$class.'</Value>'."\n";
        print FILE '</Feature>'."\n";
        print FILE '</Annotation>'."\n";
        print FILE '</AnnotationSet>'."\n";

        ##end of the document
        print FILE '</GateDocument>'."\n";
        $i++;
    }
    close FILE;
}    
close IN;
```

Comment: Here is several problems in your code, but adding only one comment: did you checked https://metacpan.org/pod/NLP::GATE what is _Handle GATE documents and annotations_ ?